# How can i get a Firebase FCM token in ios and andriod .NET Maui application? And what nuget package is the best for this

Tags: android, ios, maui, .net-7.0

I had a Xamarin application that i migrated to .net7 Maui, currently having issues implementing Firebase push notifications, I did use a package: Plugin.Firebase but that completely broke my project, the errors (266 errors) I received when using Plugin.Firebase:

Error  MSB3030  Could not copy the file "C:\Users\Username.nuget\packages\xamarin.firebase.ios.cloudfirestore\8.10.0.3\lib\net6.0-ios15.4\Firebase.CloudFirestore.resources\grpc.xcframework\ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator\grpc.framework\PrivateHeaders\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\global_subchannel_pool.h" because it was not found. C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    4879

Once i removed the Plugin.Firebase package all the errors goes away, so I believe their is some conflicts with that package and other packages in my application.

I used the following article:
[https://cedricgabrang.medium.com/firebase-push-notifications-in-net-maui-android-32c808844d7e](https://stackoverflow.com)

What other packages is available and that works with .NET Maui?

All I need is the FCM token so that I can send it to my backend server and push notification from there to each device.

I tried other packages with no luck any feedback will be helpful.

Comment: what is the VS version of yours? If it is not the latest one, update it to latest and try again. I am also faced same kind of issues and after VS update all the code errors are vanished with `plugin.firebase` package.

Comment: Follow this blog: https://cedricgabrang.medium.com/firebase-push-notifications-in-net-maui-android-32c808844d7e

Answer (score 0):

You can add the nuget package `Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging` to use the FireBase FCM.

Here is the document you can refer to [.NET MAUI Push Notification for iOS](https://github.com/michalpr/Docs/blob/main/Firebase_MAUI_iOS_push_notification.md)